# Appending list elements to unordered lists

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

So for my first JavaScript project, I'm trying to make a note taking web app. I want my notes to be displayed on the right side of the screen in an unordered list. The problem is that instead of making a new li element, the code just adds the text to one list element.

So if note 1 was "walk the dog", it would make a list element with that string.
If note 2 was "do the laundry", it would just alter the list element and make it "walk the dogdo the laundry"

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="noteArea">
        <div id="noteButtons"></div>
        <textarea name="" id="noteText" cols="62" rows="40"></textarea>
        <button id="noteSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="noteList">
        <h1>Note List</h1>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
const noteLi = document.createElement("li");

const submitButton = document.querySelector("#noteSubmit");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", createNote);

function createNote(e){
   let text = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('#noteText').value);
   noteLi.appendChild(text);
   document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(noteLi);
}
```

Comment: You only create one `li` element. Move the line with `createElement("li")` into `createNote`.

Comment: expanding from what @HereticMonkey has already suggested, you need to look into **lexical scoping**.. the function each time is invoked has - for lack of better words - no knowledge that you want __it__ to create a new LI element. Why? because that LI is not **local** to the function (encapsulated within the function). LI is **declared** and **initialised** in the **global** scope..

Comment: @HereticMonkey It worked, thanks so much!

Comment: @rags2riches Thanks for pinpointing the root of the problem on my part. I'll brush up on scoping

Comment: You could also expand your use of this by maintaining an array. Each element in the array representing each of your unordered list elements... in case you desired to use your 'notes' to explore new concepts and implementations (which is a very practical use in a real website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#noteSubmit");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", createNote);

function createNote(e){
const noteLi = document.createElement("li");
let text = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('#noteText').value);
noteLi.appendChild(text);
document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(noteLi);
}
```

This code works fine.

The new list element should be created everytime you run the submit function.